# Waiting for connection(netbeans-xdebug)

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

i am trying to debug my php code in netbeans. the code runs perfectly but i am unable to debug it(doesn't stop at breakpoint) and the code runs normally.

i have tried every possible workaround in order to get my xdebug working and has been stuck from past few days.. anyone out there who can help me sort out this issue.

xdebug configuration in .ini file:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=mgiplocalhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

here mgiplocalhost is my virtual host.
i have tried with other possibilities as well like localhost and ip address but the waiting for connection still exists.

In netbeans->tools->options->debugging when i set my port as 9000 and debug it asks me to change the port since port 9000 is already in use. i have changing the port but the problem persist.

please i need help to sort it out asap. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but thought this should have an answer! To get Xdebug working, the minimal configuration I found I needed in the **php.ini** file was the line to load the extension:

`zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll` (pointing to the downloaded dll from the [Xdebug site](http://xdebug.org/download.php))

And the following Xdebug settings also placed further down in the **php.ini** file:

```
[Xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

The Xdebug default port was 9000, and that is also what Netbeans was using (Tools -> Options... -> PHP -> Debugging.) If 9000 is in use, you could also set that in Netbeans to be 9001 and in the **php.ini** file add the line `xdebug.remote_port=9001` with your other xdebug settings.

Then try it out after restarting the server.